# Where does cmus keep its library and cache files?

Tags: cmus

I just started using the [cmus console music player](https://cmus.github.io/). `man cmus-tutorial` tells how to add music to its "library", and says:

> Note: cmus does not move, duplicate or change your files. It just
>   remembers where they are and caches the metadata (duration, artist,
>   etc.)

Where does it "remember" this, in case I want to reset it?

Answer (score 2):

### `~/.cmus` or `~/.config/cmus`

I'd seen some references to `~/.cmus`, but apparently the newer versions put things in `~/.config/cmus`.

Actually, it shows this at the top of the screen in the library and playlist views, I just hadn't noticed.